Change coefficient in multivariate model "abess" package
I'm trying to change the coefficients of a trained model, something like this
set.seed(1)
y <- cumsum(rnorm(100))
x <- 1:length(y)

LR <- lm(y~x)
pr <- predict(LR, cbind.data.frame(x))

plot(x, y, t="l")
lines(pr, col=4)


changing some model coefficients, just for example
LR$coefficients <- LR$coefficients + 0.05
new_pr <- predict(LR, cbind.data.frame(x))
lines(new_pr, col=2, lty=2)


Now I would like to do the same with a model from the abess package with many response functions
y <- matrix(rnorm(200), ncol = 4) ; colnames(y) <- paste0("y", 1:ncol(y))
x <- matrix(rnorm(200), ncol = 4) ; colnames(x) <- paste0("x", 1:ncol(x))
library(abess)
################ Multivariate gaussian model ################
abess_fit <- abess(x, y, family = "mgaussian")

But the problem is that when I try to get the coefficients of the model, I get several sets of coefficients, in this example there are 5 of them but the number depends on the data.
abess_fit[["beta"]]

$`0`
4 x 4 diagonal matrix of class "ddiMatrix"
   y1 y2 y3 y4
x1  0  .  .  .
x2  .  0  .  .
x3  .  .  0  .
x4  .  .  .  0

$`1`
4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
           y1         y2        y3        y4
x1  .         .          .          .       
x2 -0.1015219 0.02199386 0.1122985 -0.250586
x3  .         .          .          .       
x4  .         .          .          .       

$`2`
4 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
            y1          y2          y3          y4
x1  .           .           .           .         
x2 -0.09682036  0.03178114  0.11441030 -0.24966314
x3  .           .           .           .         
x4 -0.11844742 -0.24657644 -0.05320414 -0.02324879

$`3` .. $`4` .. $`5`

and
abess_fit[["intercept"]]

[[1]]
[1]  0.10044828  0.11732645 -0.15248544  0.07686929

[[2]]
[1]  0.1096521  0.1153325 -0.1626663  0.0995871

[[3]] .. [[4]] .. [[5]]

I don’t understand why there are several sets and what set of coefficients I need to change my model.
